# Highchart xAxis "6 Hours Ago" ,"5 Hours ago" and so on. while my chart is updating

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, highcharts, arduino

I am using a JSON to fetch the data to my database. Is there a way the xAxis turn to 6 hours ago, 5 hours ago, 4 hours ago, 3 hours ago, 2 hours ago, 1 hour ago while the chart is updating? Because i am using a LM35 to import the temperature into my database. I really need your help. ( Sorry for my bad english). Thanks in advance. Here is my code

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });





$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {        
                renderTo: 'container',

                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 65,
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature Over Time',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
            tickInterval:12,
            range:20,
            categories:[]
            },


            scrollbar: {
                enabled: true,
        barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        barBorderRadius: 7,
        barBorderWidth: 0,
        buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
        buttonBorderWidth: 0,
        buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
        buttonBorderRadius: 7,
        rifleColor: 'yellow',
        trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
        trackBorderWidth: 1,
        trackBorderColor: 'silver',
        trackBorderRadius: 7
            },      


            yAxis: {
            min:0,
            max: 40,
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                },


                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
                },


            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }

            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: []
        }

       refreshDiv();
       $(window).scrollLeft($(window).width());
       setInterval(refreshDiv, 300000);
       function refreshDiv(){
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
        options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            options.series[0] = json[1];
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
        }

    });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Can you put a piece of code, please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code:

```
$.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
```

You can use [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories%28%29) function and [setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29), but I advice to create chart and then only use [addPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint%28%29) function in intervals like in the example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update .In case when xAxis will not be correct, you can ise datetime [type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) and reversed parameter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.reversed)